# NextJs - getServerSideProps never get invoked in custom app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my custom nextJs app `getServerSideProps` never get invoked in pages.
Here are the content of my `pages/_app` directory:

AuthWrapper:

```
const AuthWrapper = (props) => {

//some auth logic

  return (
    <LayoutWrapper {...props} />
  )
}

export default AuthWrapper
```

LayoutWrapper:

```
const LayoutWrapper = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Layout>
        <Header />
        <Content >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Content>
        <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>ABC, Inc.</Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  )
}

LayoutWrapper.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.node,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object
}

export default LayoutWrapper
```

App: (index.js)

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      //someProps
      >
      <Provider store={props.store}>
        <AuthWrapper {...props} />
      </Provider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  )
}

App.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.any
}

export default withRedux(initStore)(App)
```

Now in my custom page:
`pages/myPage/index.js`

```
const MyPage = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <>
     {/* someHtml  */}
    </>
  )
}

MyPage.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.string
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  console.log("inside getServerSideProps method")
  return { props: { data: "Hello World" } };
}

export default React.memo(MyPage)
```

`getServerSideProps` never get invoked

Making sure all imports are done correctly in all files

Comment: Have you had any progress with this @Affan Shahab? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I can't remember exactly, I ended up taking some other approach I think. Sorry can't remember what was it.